# How do I use a specific IP proxy with TOR?

Tags: proxy

I have some specific proxy IP addresses. They currently work fine in my standard browser, when changing the proxy settings.

I am looking for a way to be able to use TOR and then a specific IP address on top of TOR. So the website I visit will see the specific IP I set. The reason i need to do this is because certain websites I use, require certain IPs.

I have read this page:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorPlusVPN
"You -> Tor -> Proxy
"One way to do that is proxychains. Another way would be to use a Transparent Proxy and then either proxify (set proxy settings) or socksify (use helper applications to force your application to use a proxy) the programs you want to chain inside your Transparent Proxy client machine. "

It seems a little complicated though. Wondering if anybody has any success with this or may be able to assist me in setting this up?

Comment: Tor Browser has protections against the SOCKS port reported from the control port not matching the SOCKS port in use by the browser, it's there to make it more difficult for local attackers to redirect Tor's traffic into a malicious shim (e.g. HackingTeam's "Project X").

Comment: or accidental misconfiguration.